# How to solve this 4x4 equation system for a cubic spline?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics, spline

I am attempting to create a simple cubic spline between these lines:
[image: Cubic]

I have worked out the four equations as:

- **(1)** $1 = An^3 + Bn^2 + Cn + D$
- **(2)** $g^{m-t} = At^3 + Bt^2 + Ct + D$
- **(3)** $0 = 3An^2 + 2Bn + C$
- **(4)** $ln(g) * (-g)^{m-t} = 3At^2 + 2Bt + C$

I need to solve for $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ in order to graph my spline.

But I am mostly stuck. I tried subtracting $3$ and $4$ to eliminate $C$, and tried rearranging and dividing $2$ by $1$ to eliminate $C$, but I can't figure out how to work through all of it.

I tried a variety of online 4x4 solvers but they won't take these equations since they have other variables in them ($n$, $m$, $t$, $g$).

How could one solve this? Are there any automatic programs that could handle this type of thing to make it easier?

Comment: How much linear algebra do you know?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician. I have basic high school math and I took one or two stats courses in university. That's it. I need this for a personal project I'm working on.

Comment: Start changing notations : say $\alpha=g^{m-t}$ and $\beta=\ln(g)\, (-g)^{m-t}$. The solution is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found wxMaxima which can solve these things, but what a mess the answer is:

[image: WxMaxima solution]

Either way, this looks like a quick easy free way to solve this type of problem.